# AS3 OggVorbis - is there a precompiled SWC available?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oggvorbis, flascc

I would like to use OggVorbis sound files in a flash project, and while I realize I can compile a SWC with crossbridge, that is a little over my head, so I was wondering if anyone knows of a ready to use SWC library available for download. I have googled this to death without much luck.

Alternatively, if anyone knows of a good walkthrough for compiling this library that would be great too. I have crossbridge set up and working, but when it gets to the part of making a swc interface I got a bit lost, and I'm on a time-table to get this working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This one works pretty good, and has compiled SWC files.
http://labs.byhook.com/2011/02/22/ogg-vorbis-encoder-decoder-for-flash/

Comment: Well, "good" is a realtive term, it's pretty slow, and besides it's not FlasCC but the totally outdated Alchemy.